# html5 validate form with required="true" and custom check

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

What I'm looking for: way to have innate html 5 form validation using the required="true", where if the user clicks the "Submit" button, the first thing that happens is the automatic html 5 validation where it checks to see if "username" is provided by the user.  If it's not, then it displays the ugly error bubble.

If it is provided, however, I then have my own custom validation for checking against the db if the username exists.  If it does, then return true (allow submission), false otherwise.  What's happening: the form is getting submitted.  It's like it does not wait for the success callback to return true/false on whether or not it should be submitted.

I hope that's clear enough!  Code below:

html:

```
<form>
<input type="text" required="true" id="username" />
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

js:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'usernamechecker.php?username=' + $("#username").val(),
      success: function(resp) {
        if (!resp.UsernameExists) {
          return true; // allow form submission
        }
        return false; // do not allow form submission
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "async: false" as a parameter to your ajax call in order to force the call to finish before continuing on with the rest of the code.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
      async: false,
      url: 'usernamechecker.php?username=' + $("#username").val(),
      timeout: 1000,
      success: function(resp) {
        if (resp.UsernameExists) {
          event.preventDefault(); // do not allow form submission
        },
      error: function() {
          //fall back code when there's an error or timeout
      },
    });
});
```

Comment: This is probably a really bad idea, as that'll cause the browser to completely freeze while waiting for the response.  There are few cases where synchronous ajax makes sense (in my personal experience, none, but I'll give the idea the benefit of doubt).

Comment: I really like this idea.  But, do I still have the "return true" in the success callback?

Comment: True. This answers his question, but he'll definitely need have to set a timeout aswell and probably a loading graphic.

Comment: I love this idea, but, in my callback I have "return false" and it still submits the form.

Comment: no, you can simply check if the username exists.. if it does, prevent form submission by running `event.preventDefault();` (i passed `event` as a parameter in the `submit(function(event){`

Comment: @CoryDanielson - you rock. Thanks so much, this is perfect! I have to wait 1 min to click on the check mark to mark this as the answer.  I will tho, in 60...59...

Comment: @IanDavis Dude, seriously, synchronous ajax is really not what you should be doing to your users.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return a value *through* a callback like that. The callback for "success" won't run until the "ajax" call has completed, **long** after the "submit" handler has already returned.

Instead of that, I'd just do the submit and let it return with an error if there are server-side issues (like "username in use" or whatever).  There's no point making two round-trips. If there are no problems, it can just complete the operation and return whatever results page you want.